# How can I block users from accessing a certain ProGet feed?

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I am using ProGet 1.0.9 and I can't figure out how to block a certain set of users from accessing a NuGet feed. I still want these users to be able access all the rest of the feeds, I just want one particular feed to be denied. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you've discovered how to do this yet, but under "Administration" > "Privileges and Roles", there's an option to add a feed-level denied privilege to a specific user or group:

[image: Deny access to ProGet feed]

Make sure to select the "Administrators" role if you want to deny complete access to the feed.